# contact list in angular js working in older version not in new version

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js and I am learning from this [Site](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-controller-tutorial/).  Here I am trying to do the same contact list

It was working fine with older version angular js ver 1.1.1. When I am trying using 1.3.1 it was not working

Here is the fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/aLDJJ/1655/)

```
 <div ng-app="" ng-controller="ContactController">
    <p>Enter an email address in below textbox and press Add button:</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newcontact" placeholder="Email" />
    <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
    <h2>Contacts</h2>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">{{ contact }} </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    function ContactController($scope) {
        $scope.contacts = ["maha@gmail.com", "hello@email.com"];

        $scope.add = function () {
            $scope.contacts.push($scope.newcontact);
            $scope.newcontact = "";
        }
    }
</script>
```

But not with new version of angularjs. Could anyone help me why the above is not working with new version.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define your controller under Angular's [module](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module), like:

```
angular.module("MyApp",[])
    .controller("ContactController" , function($scope) {

    // ...

});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aLDJJ/1657/